# htaccess redirection with exclusion

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://shop.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://shop.com/index.php?id_category=12&controller=category [R=301,L]
```

I want :

- my `index.php` to be redirected to `index.php?id_category=12&controller=category`.
- override this redirection if the Referer is equal to `http://shop.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account`

It seems the third RewriteCond, which is supposed to create the exception, doesn't match the request to `index.php` when the Referer is equal to `http://shop.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account`. As a result, the RewriteRule is taken into account, whereas it shouldn't.

This behavior makes me think `%{HTTP_REFERER}` doesn't include params in URL (in this case: `id_category=12&controller=category`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does. You just have to escape the question mark. Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://shop.com/index.php\?controller=authentication&back=my-account [NC]
```